# javascript function returning an undefined object

Tags: javascript

i saw this code online and this is its contents.

```
       var shoppingcart = (function ()  {

             var _calculatePrice = function() {
                 return this.price * this.amount;
          };
          return {
              calculatePrice : _calculatePrice
           }
        })();

        var goods = {
           name: 'hammer',
           price: 199,
           amount: 2
        }
        shoppingCart.calculatePrice.call(goods)
```

And this is where i am not comfortable. the function returning an undefined object in {calculatePrice : _calculatePrice}. how does that really work? i thought it will do no harm to return just _calculatePrice

Comment: What is an "undefined object"? It seems pretty well defined to me.

Comment: how so then, cos i think from the code var _calculatePrice was defined, but calculatePrice was return . unless of course both _calculatePrice and calculatePrice are the same thing

Comment: The function return a function which can be called using the calculatePrice name. _calculatePrice is the internal name and definion of the returned function (which could have been called calculatePrice also)

Comment: change shoppingcart to shoppingCart at line 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly Typo at line 1.: change `shoppingcart` to `shoppingCart`

```js
var shoppingCart = (function() {

  var _calculatePrice = function() {
    return this.price * this.amount;
  };
  return {
    calculatePrice: _calculatePrice
  }
})();

var goods = {
  name: 'hammer',
  price: 199,
  amount: 2
}
console.log(shoppingCart.calculatePrice.call(goods))
```

**Explanation:**

The returned object is:

```
{
    calculatePrice: _calculatePrice
}
```

It's property `calculatePrice` is variable `_calculatePrice`.

`_calculatePrice` references a function that returns a calculated Number.

`.call()` function helps you call a function with reference at global scope. Thats why the calculation function uses `this.price` & `this.amount`.

Comment: y down voted? pls leave a comment. it clearly runs and outputs.

Comment: my confusion is this maybe am new to the language, but i thought the return statement is not very straightfoward, return { calculatePrice: _calculatePrice }. can pls explain to me what that line actually means?

Comment: @pedroyanky hope u understood. pls accept the answer & upvote if you did.

Answer (score -1):

There is a typo : you declare a var shoppingcart and then you call it shoppingCart with C instead of c.

try to change de var declaration to: var shoppingCart = ....